# Laplace transform time shift step function disappears

Tags: laplace-transform

Please find the flaw in my reasoning.

Given a function $f(t)$, the Laplace transform is
$F(s) = \int_0^\infty dt f(t) e^{-st}$. And the inverse is $f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma ds F(s) e^{st}$ where $\gamma$ indicates a path in the region of convergence.

Define a time shifted version $g(t) = f(t-a) u(t-a)$, where $u$ is the step function, and $a>0$.

You can prove that $G(s) = e^{-as}F(s)$ using the time shift property. But when I try to compute the inverse the step function is gone.

$g(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}(G(s))=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma ds G(s) e^{st}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma ds F(s) e^{s(t-a)} = f(t-a)$

Where in the last step I used the definition of the inverse Laplace transform at the start of my question. So where did the step function go?

Edit: Added the assumption $a>0$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't recover the Heaviside function inside $g(t)$ after inverting the Fourier transform, because you calculated $G(s)$ as if it was absent from $g(t)$ at the start. Indeed, one has :
$$
G(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t-a)u(t-a)e^{-st}\,\mathrm{d}t = e^{-sa}\int_\color{red}{-a}^\infty f(t)u(t)e^{-st}\,\mathrm{d}t \neq e^{-sa}F(s) \mathrm{\;\;if\;\;} a<0
$$
Note that products of functions are mapped to convolution products by Fourier/Laplace transforms (although more caution has to be shown with the path of integration in the case of Laplace), i.e. $\mathscr{L}[f_1f_2] = F_1*F_2$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. $G(s)=\int_0^\infty f(t-a) u(t-a) e^{-st}dt=\int_a^\infty f(t-a) e^{-st}dt=\int_0^\infty f(t') e^{-s(t'+a)}dt'=e^{-as} \int_0^\infty f(t') e^{-st'}dt' = e^{-as}F(s)$. Alternatively, in your formula, you could remove the bit from $-a$ to $0$ in the integration bounds because $u(t)=0$ for $t<0$.

Comment: @MikeJordan   Not in the case $a=-\alpha<0$, because $G(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t-a)u(t-a)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^\infty f(t-a)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t = \int_\alpha^\infty f(t')e^{-s(t'+a)}\mathrm{d}t'$, since $u(t-a) = u(t+\alpha) = 1$ $\forall t>0$. Your formula is true only if $a$ is positive.

Comment: Ok, I should have specified $a>0$ from the start (I will edit the question). So in that case $G(s) = e^{-as}F(s)$. But I still don't get where the step function went.

Comment: @MikeJordan Because Laplace transform is not bijective; indeed, if $a>0$, then $f(t-a)u(t-a)$ and $f(t-a)$ have the same transforms, so that the inverse transformation cannot distinguish them. More generally, it is due to the fact that the (one-sided) Laplace transform doesn't take into account the behaviour of its integrand outside the domain of integration; in consequence, inverse transforms are to be understood as equivalence classes. For example, the Heaviside function and the constant function 1, or $\delta(x-1)$ and $f\equiv0$, are indistinguishable in the eyes of the Laplace transform.